# Git merge & Pull code and Local Changes Lost

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging, git-pull

Here i am writing the git commands i followed to commit the code.

```
git merge <branch1> --no-commit
```

So i got the code from that branch and i started working on it. I did merge code into master only. Now after i have completed my code and try to get changes from master as others also working on it.

```
git pull origin master
```

I Got error Saying that MERGE_HEAD Exists please commit your files. So i did commit the code by entering these commands.

```
git add .
git commit -m "<commit message>"
```

Now i tried to pull the code by rebasing it as i normally do.

```
git pull origin master --rebase
```

Now everything is fine and commit also looks good. So i have gone to codebase and checked the files. All my changes are gone. Where did i do wrong?? Still I dont know. Please help me to find whats wrong. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you find your changes in `git reflog`?

Comment: You have to pull before merging your branch. You also need to rebase before merging. You have this error message because you are trying to merge two branches with different histories

Comment: "Now everything is fine and commit also looks good. So i have gone to codebase and checked the files. All my changes are gone" - could you explain more? What do you mean by "commit looks good" - do you see there your changes? What, then, is the "codebase", where you don't see the changes?

Comment: @max360 before I tried pulling the changes from master, I did have all those changes. But after pulling the code, now its gone.

Comment: @choroba f3b1eb4 HEAD@{11}: commit (merge): <commit message>
is what I found atleast related. But how to see those changes i dont know.

Comment: Use `git show` to see the changes in a given commit.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps to bring your changes from your branch to master :

```
git checkout master
```

> that is the branch where you want to push your changes

```
git pull origin master
```

> to retrieve commits of your team

```
git checkout your-branch
```

> to retrieve your branch

```
git rebase master
```

> to retrieve all the commits of master and after that put your changes

```
git checkout -b your-branch.1
```

> you cannot push your commits on your-branch because your remote is not the same that your local branch as rebase rewrites history

```
git push origin your-branch.1
```

> push your branch that you are ready to merge

```
git checkout master
```

> that is the branch where you want to merge

```
git merge --no-commit --squash your-branch.1
```

> to merge your branch with master. Squash will bring all your commits in one. No commit will let you write a nice commit message

```
git commit -m "here is my commit message"
```

> be kind let your team members what your changes are about

```
git push
```

> publish your changes

Comment: so you are creating a new branch for these new changes. why?? I have got my branch already. So why should I create a new branch? Can you explain a little bit.

Comment: Rebasing your branch with master will change history of commits : you will get all the commits from master + yours on top. But these changes are only applied on your local git branch, so your remote branch will get a different history and git won't allow you to push your local branch for that reason. That's why you have to create a new branch (.1 is just to give a clue that the same branch but a "newer" version)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> git merge <branch1> --no-commit
> ```
>
> So i got the code from that branch and i started working on it.

This is not an answer, but here you seem to doing it wrong. By not committing you are mixing your development changes with previous merge. This can mess further history analysis.

Comment: I wrongly understood the meaning of --no-commit. So I did like that and started coding. But there is no problem while I am changing the code before merging it also. So I continued. Now my code is gone and doing it again.